# PYQT Background image not showing correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, background-image

I created a file using QT Designer, and I uploaded a background image. This file works well and the image appears in the background.
However, when the file is import to the main file, the image does not appear in the background correctly.

and project link
https://github.com/ahmedlam3y/GarageSystem

Comment: i think you can help  
https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is not the main window, but it is ًWidget so the picture was not visible in the background and one of the Widgets has been set to the mainWindow so it work correctly 
and The code for solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets as Q
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import image_rc
from SignIN import Ui_Form as SignInForm
from WelFrame import Ui_Form as WelFrameForm
from SignUp import Ui_Form as SignUpForm
from Accounting import Ui_Form as AccountForm


class SignIn(Q.QWidget, SignInForm):  # Widget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SignIn, self).__init__(parent)
        Q.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        oImage = QImage("GTR.png")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(600, 360))  # resize Image to widgets size
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))  # 10 = WindowRole
        self.setPalette(palette)


class WelFrame(Q.QMainWindow, WelFrameForm):  # MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Q.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class SignUp(Q.QWidget, SignUpForm):  # Widget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Q.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        oImage = QImage("GTR.png")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(600, 360))  # resize Image to widgets size
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))  # 10 = WindowRole
        self.setPalette(palette)


class Accout(Q.QWidget, AccountForm):  # Widget
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Q.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        oImage = QImage("GTR.png")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(600, 360))  # resize Image to widgets size
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))  # 10 = WindowRole
        self.setPalette(palette)


def foo(w1, w2):
    w1.show()
    w2.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Q.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wel = WelFrame()
    signIn = SignIn()
    signUp = SignUp()
    accout = AccountForm()
    wel.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: foo(signIn, wel))
    wel.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: foo(signUp, wel))
    signIn.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: foo(wel, signIn))
    signUp.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: foo(wel, signUp))
    wel.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```